# Drupal Caching - Missing rows field

Tags: views, caching

I have a view set on home page: http://www.userbase.com/

some of the row fields are blank for anonymous users. Logged in users see it fine. I assume its issue with caching. The site is getting approx 5-10 new content every minute through api which seems not getting pulled in cache.

Any ides?

I am using following cache plugins:

Block Cache Alter
Render cache
Render cache for comments added to a node
Render cache for display suite views integration
Render cache for node_show
Render cache for views_plugin_row_node_view
Safe cache_form Clear

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated!